# Intro to Stats by Starting with Regression

Tags: regression, references

I am looking for an introduction to statistics book that starts with regression analysis, and uses regression as a foundation to introduce all basic concepts.

When I was a graduate student, I remember reading an introduction to business statistics that started with regression. The approach seems unorthodox, but I liked it. Any suggestion to any book that follows such an approach would be great.

Thanks,
TCS

Comment: Regression is an introduction to statistical learning, it is not an intro to statistics. As such a beginner statistics text will not have linear regression as chapter 1.

Comment: @Victor "Introduction" and "For beginners" are not synonymous.  Most mathematicians, for example, are acquainted with "Introductory" texts that start at extremely advanced levels. Even so, there are good stats books for beginners that cover regression and correlation before they introduce probability, sampling, or hypothesis tests.

Answer (score 1):

You have many options to start. So, I would recommend  *"Machine Learning with R"* or *"An introduction to Statistical Learning with Applications in R"*. Both books use to show at same time theory and application. The first book's not free.

Comment: Could you give a brief explanation *why* you recommend these particular books?

Comment: I recommend this books, because both have an mathematics approach , with a good computational representation of this concepts, beyond have  a very good didatics.